# Is it more efficient to convert to string than to iterate an object to find something?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have a dilemma of which case is more efficient.
I have a javascript array with this structure

```
elements = 
  [ { id: 'uuid',         children: [] } 
  , { id: 'uuid',         children: [] } 
  , { id: 'uuid',         children: 
      [ { id: 'uuid',     children: [] } 
      , { id: 'uuid',     children: 
          [ { id: 'uuid', children: [] } 
          , { id: 'uuid', children: [] } 
          ] 
        } 
      , { id: 'uuid',     children: [] } 
      ] 
    } 
  ]
```

To find a specific object, I have two ways of working, one is to iterate each element until I find it and the other is to convert it to string and if the id exists in the children, I enter the node

```
function findElementById(id_, elements){
for (el of elements){
    if(el.id == id_) return el
    if(JSON.stringify(el.children).includes(id_)) return findElementById(id, el.children)
}
}
```

```
function findElementById(id_, elements){
for (el of elements){
    if(el.id == id_) return el
    if(el.children.length > 0) result = findElementById(id, el.children)
    if (result) return result
}
}
```

It's efficient to convert to string to avoid entering nodes that will not return anything or in cases where the object is very large, converting to string uses a lot of resources.

Comment: I think keep it an array. For sure. Because how else are you going to stringify an object if not by iterating *all* of it?

Comment: Create an index (an object mapping keys,`uuid` in this case, to elements) into the tree. Then all your lookups are just `index[id_]`.

Comment: it all depends on the logic of your uuids. Otherwise, the string format has its limits anyway.

Comment: `stringify` is going to traverse the whole recursive structure anyway, just recurse with the specific purpose.

Comment: @danh—yes, but it's written in the native code so also runs hugely faster than javascript and is likely using optimisations not available in POJS.

Comment: Yo, is there any reason you used the [binary-search-tree] tag? It doesn't seem like you have a BST here... Maybe that's what you're shooting for. My answer won't take you that far, but learning about binary search is a good way towards the binary search tree.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you maintain a flat, sorted array of nodes:

```
const flat = Array.from('12345678').map(x => ({ 'id': `uuid${x}`, 'children': [] }))
```

... and assemble a tree on top of that (this is equivalent to your `elements`):

```
const tree = Array.from('012').map(x => flat[x])
flat[2].children.push(flat[3], flat[4], flat[7])
flat[4].children.push(flat[5], flat[6])
```

Now so long as you keep the array sorted you can conduct a binary search on it using functions like:

```
const id_compare = (x, y) => (x.id > y.id) - (x.id < y.id)
const search = (tab, element, compare) =>
    function search_(min, max) {
       let x = min + (max - min >> 1)
       switch (compare(element, tab[x])) {
           case -1: return min < x && search_(min, x)
           case  0: return tab[x]
           case +1: return x < max && search_(x, max)
       }
   }(0, tab.length)
```

Due to unforeseen circumstances I can only postulate that this will be an order of magnitude faster than your first solution. I can't do any practical tests (beyond searching for and comparing all elements, and some `'rubbish'`, such as below) because I don't have a computer to test on; this is all based on theory (an O(log n) solution might be faster than an O(n) function ‍♂️)

```
let walk = (node, fun) => node.forEach(n => fun(n) && n.children.length && walk(n.children, fun))
walk([ ... tree, { 'id': 'rubbish', 'children': [] }], n => !console.log(`testing ${n.id}: ${n === search(flat, { 'id': n.id }, id_compare)}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to find a node by its id *once*, it won't make a big deal (although you could do some benchmarking and choose). But, if you are going to make several searches in that tree structure, then it is better to traverse the tree only once in order to make a map from id to object, and then a search simplifies to a lookup in that map:

```js
const elements = 
  [ { id: '123456',         children: [] } 
  , { id: '654987',         children: [] } 
  , { id: '951846',         children: 
      [ { id: '753421',     children: [] } 
      , { id: '987575',     children: 
          [ { id: '984625', children: [] } 
          , { id: '165896', children: [] } 
          ] 
        } 
      , { id: '546852',     children: [] } 
      ] 
    } 
  ];

const getPairs = elements => 
    elements.flatMap(node => [[node.id, node], ...getPairs(node.children)])
const map = new Map(getPairs(elements));

console.log(map.get('753421'));
console.log(map.get('987575'));
```